# Переклад тенісної термінології: backhand та forehand

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

У словнику backhand перекладається як "удар зліва", а forehand - як "удар справа". Але це не зовсім коректні терміни, адже для Федерера (він правша) backhand дійсно є ударом зліва, а ось для Надаля (він шульга) backhand - це все-таки удар справа. До того ж, в цих перекладах зайва увага приділяється тому, з якого боку йде удар, а насправді скоріше важлива манера, "відкритою" чи "закритою" рукою йде удар.

Чи україномовні тенісні коментатори користуються запозиченнями "бекхенд" та "форхенд"? Які ще можуть бути варіанти?

Comment: на мою думку: forehand - це калька з forehead (лоб) і як я розумію значить 'долоня' а backhand - калька з кальки backhead (opposite to forehead, потилиця) і значить 'тильна сторона долоні', або скальковано 'тилоня' :)

Comment: Я не думаю, що коректно forehand називати калькою з forehead, просто така сама схема словоутворення: fore (попереду) + hand (рука), але таких слів в англійський чимало. Слово "тилоня" мені подобається, куменде, але навряд чи є шанси прижитися, хіба що якийсь харизматичний коментатор все-таки почне вживати. Мене б форхенд та бекхенд влаштували би точно, але я не пурист і не проти запозичень. 

З іншого боку, це не нові терміни, а терміни ще з 19 століття (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=forehand), тому більше цікавлять сталі вирази, а не новоутворення, певен, що мають бути.

Comment: Так, "відкрита" та "закрита" рука дійсно були б кращими варіантами. Але ця термінологія вже розповсюджена у інших видах спорту стосовно ударів із зігнутими чи розігнутими пальцями.

Comment: як я можу собі це уявити, ще є аспект напрямку - удар всередину (forehand) або назовні (backhand)

Comment: Можна замість "відкрита рука" спробувати сказати "відкритий удар"/"закритий удар".

Comment: Artеmix, мені така термінологія подобається і здається вдалою - підкреслюємо манеру удару, і вона не залежить від того, правша чи шульга гравець.

Comment: Настільний теніс так само використовує `удар зліва` та `удар справа` як от, наприклад, ось в цьому [виданні](http://er.nau.edu.ua:8080/bitstream/NAU/13748/1/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%20%D0%90%D0%90%D0%90%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F.pdf) Національного
авіаційного університету. Так, "зліва" та "справа" геть змінює сенс для шульги.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81#.D0.A2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.96.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.96.D1.8F) використовує **бекхенд** (удар закритою ракеткою) та **форхенд** (удар відкритою ракеткою).

Comment: Ці терміни, до речі, також важливі й для настільного тенісу (пінг-понгу).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Пошук у статтях

О. П. Коваль у статті «[СЕМАНТИКО-ФУНКЦІОНАЛЬНІ ОСОБЛИВОСТІ ТЕРМІНА
НАСТІЛЬНОГО ТА ВЕЛИКОГО ТЕНІСУ](http://nbuv.gov.ua/j-pdf/Nznuoaf_2012_27_10.pdf)» вживає лише *удар зліва*:

> Наприклад:
>
> – ***backhand*** – a stroke with the back of the hand facing toward one’s opponent [11, с. 12] – **удар по м’ячу, що летить зліва** (удар, при якому кисть, що стискає ракетку, спрямована до м’яча тильною стороною).
>
> Узус цього терміна у спеціальних спортивних текстах ілюструє його ширшу семантику.
>
> – *One of the longest-running debates in tennis concerns the **backhand** – Одне із спірних питань у тенісі стосується виконання **удару зліва**.*
>
> – *More difficult to hit **slice backhands** since you aren’t used to letting go with one hand – Набагато важче виконувати **“обрубаний“ удар зліва**, оскільки ви ще не звикли виконувати його однією рукою* [14, с. 67-68 issue 11].
>
> Як бачимо у спеціальному тексті термін семантично насичений уточнюючими елементами, утворюючи “видові кореляти основного поняття” [8, с. 10], тобто термінологічні словосполучення.

Він же у статті «[ТЕРМІНОТВІРНІ ПРОЦЕСИ У ПІДМОВІ НАСТІЛЬНОГО ТЕНІСУ](http://nbuv.gov.ua/j-pdf/Mik_2011_14_8_23.pdf)» перекладає *backhand chop* як *підрізка зліва*.

І. М. Фесенко у статті «[СПОРТИВНА ТЕРМІНОЛОГІЯ СУЧАСНОЇ АНГЛІЙСЬКОЇ МОВИ
ТА ЇЇ ЛЕКСИКОГРАФІЧНИЙ ОПИС](http://nbuv.gov.ua/j-pdf/Novfil_2011_46_63.pdf)» вживає два варіанти для *backhand* (але чомусь лише один для *forehand*):

> *When Hingis failed to put away an overhead that would have given her two match points, Williams passed her with a **backhand**, than won the final four games*.
>
> Тенісний термін **backhand** перекладається як **удар зліва**, або **бекхенд**.
>
> *One day I saw players who tried to generate a heavy topspin by using Western grip on the **forehand***.
>
> Це речення дозволяє одразу розглянути три тенісних терміна: topspin – удар iз верхньою підкруткою, кручений удар, чи топспін,термін western grip не можна віднести до термінів, що позначають удари, бо цей термін змальовує техніку гри, однак дамо i його переклад – західна хватка.
>   Тенісний термін **forehand** перекладається як **удар справa**.

В. Мулик у статті «[Визначення взаємозв’язку морфологічних показників, окремих рухових якостей і виконання елементів техніки юних тенісистів 6–8 років](http://nbuv.gov.ua/j-pdf/Fvs_2012_3_90.pdf)» вживає терміни *відкрита ракетка* і *закрита ракетка*:

> Установлено, що на виконання перебивання тенісного м’яча **«відкритою» й «закритою» ракеткою** на половину протилежного майданчика впливає довжина тіла і рук (r = 0,47 – 0,51), які дозволяють проводити удар м’яча у вищій точці, що може враховуватися при відборі юних спортсменів для занять тенісом.

О. Лазарчук у статті «[Методика побудови тренувального процесу тенісистів першого року навчання в умовах клубної системи](http://nbuv.gov.ua/j-pdf/svp_2010_2_66.pdf)» вживає *удар справа* і *удар зліва*:

> При цьому використовувалися блоки: спеціальних бігових вправ, імітаційних вправ на освоєння техніки ударів з відскоку по м’ячу без переміщення та з переміщенням по корту, вправ з кошиком на освоєння техніки **ударів справа та зліва**, з відскоку – з місця та рухливі ігри.

### Пошук у відеозаписах

На жаль, мені не вдалося знайти відеозаписи зустрічей з **українським** коментатором. Російські коментатори вживають різні терміни:  [форхенд](https://youtu.be/-sxieo3m8DM?t=46m36s), [удар справа](https://youtu.be/axgiaavk93I?t=8m16s), [бекхенд](https://youtu.be/Ji7bunwUIqU?t=3m19s), [удар справа](https://youtu.be/9018hUz8S-Y?t=12m47s)

### Аналіз процесу

*Forehand* – провідна рука з нейтрального положення заводиться вбік для удару (вправо для правші, вліво для шульги). Цьому рухові нічого не заважає, тому можна виконати глибокий замах (навіть назад), відповідно, амплітуда такого удару може бути дуже високою.

*Backhand* — провідна рука з нейтрального положення заводиться в протилежний бік для удару (вліво для правші, вправо для шульги). Цьому рухові заважає корпус (рука упирається в груди чи живіт), тому таки удар виходить слабшим. Для більшої амплітуди доводиться повертатися усім корпусом.

### Які ще можуть бути варіанти?

#### Відкритий / закритий удар

Приклад: *Одне із спірних питань у тенісі стосується виконання закритого удару*.

Плюси:

- схоже з дослівним перекладом англійських термінів ("супернику видно відкриту руку", "видно закриту руку")
- добре описує те, що відбувається (під час *forehand* гравець  "відкриває" корпус для суперника, під час *backhand* "закривається" від суперника рукою)
- підходить для тренувань. Приклад: набивати м'яч *закритою [стороною] ракеткою*, потім — *відкритою ракеткою*.

Мінуси:

- довше за оригінал: порівняти "backhand" і "закритий удар"

#### Ро́змах / відма́х (або розма́шка / відма́шка)

Приклад: *Одне із спірних питань у тенісі стосується виконання відмаху*.

Плюси:

- добре описує те, що відбувається (під час *forehand* гравець має змогу добряче [розмахнутися](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozmakhuvatysja), під час *backhand* він може лише [відмахуватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidmakhuvatysja))
- так само короткий, як і оригінал

Мінуси:

- новотвір
- погано підходить для тренувань. Приклад: набивати м'яч стороною *для розмаху*.

Comment: Дякую за таке глибоке дослідження!

Answer (score 4):

Невідповідність слів у різних мовах взагалі є досить розповсюдженим явищем, хоча у випадку великого тенісу це дуже дивна ситуація, оскільки, хоча самі терміни в англійській мові склалися у 19 сторіччі, на українські терени ця гра прийшла уже із сталою термінологією, а отже, дивно, що у грі англійського походження використовуються терміни, що не відповідають англійським.

Щодо того, якими термінами користуються українські коментатори тенісних турнірів сказати, на жаль, не можу, але моя пропозиція така:

> forehand - відкритий удар
>   backhand - закритий удар