# What are the common tennis terms in Ukrainian?

Tags: from-english, переклад, терміни

Particularly for

- [advantage set / tiebreaker set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Scoring_a_tiebreak_game)
- game
- set
- match
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)
- 15/30/40
- deuce
- advantage in / advantage out

Comment: You're asking for several terms at once. It would be better to split the question in several ones. [Here](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/79/) the question was about `forehand/backhand` only, and you may notice the size of possible research for finding a good translation *for a single term*. This question is asking for eight ones.

Comment: Closed this old question as it apparently serves an example for other users to ask multiple questions at once.